# Trouble tuning sklearn Gaussian Process Regression hyperparameters for 4D function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I've frequently been running into an issue where attempting to train a GP on a test function using adaptive sampling method frequently outputs the error

```
ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=2):
ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
  _check_optimize_result("lbfgs", opt_res)
```

However, despite numerous attempts at modifying Kernel settings, I can't get the error (specifically concerning accurately depicting the 0 level set in this problem) to decrease with a larger number of samples. I know it's not the sampling strategy, as it works on MATLAB and a lower dimensional case, and random sampling does not improve accuracy either. So I'm wondering if there are some nuances in using sklearn's Gaussian Process regression compared to MATLAB's implementation that may be missing?

Currently I'm using a constant kernel multiplied by an RBF kernel with length scale bounds [1e-3,2] where 2 is one dimension of the domain, where I often get the issue that the length scales are found to be close to or equal the upper bound. I've tried using isotropic kernels in addition to anisotropic and neither seem to help, and employing a whiteKernel does not seem to be something that would help as the data retrieved from the model function is uncorrupted. Unbounding the kernels leads to length scales larger than the domain size in all variables.

I've attached a similar version of the overall problem I'm working with that should largely demonstrate the issue I'm having:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import qmc
import random

# synthetic data function:
def squiggly31(x,y):
    nmeas = np.shape(x)[0]
    return x[:,0].reshape((nmeas,1)) + x[:,1].reshape((nmeas,1)) + x[:,2].reshape((nmeas,1)) + np.power(x[:,2]/3,3).reshape((nmeas,1)) + np.power(y,3).reshape((nmeas,1))

# sampling function
def wt_straddle(candidate_pts, gprMdl, zm_adj=0, beta_t = 1.96):
    mu, sig = gprMdl.predict(candidate_pts, return_std=True)
    mu = mu + zm_adj
    return -np.abs(mu-0) + beta_t*sig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmeas_init = np.vstack((np.asarray([-1, 1, -1]),np.asarray([1, 1, 1])))
    ymeas_init = np.asarray([[-1], [1]])
    xmeas = xmeas_init.copy()
    ymeas = ymeas_init.copy()
    zmeas = squiggly31(xmeas, ymeas)
    nd = 4

    kernel = ConstantKernel()*RBF()
    #kernel = RBF([1, 1, 1, 1], [1e-3, 2])
    kernel = ConstantKernel()*RBF([1, 1, 1, 1], [1e-3, 2])
    kernel = ConstantKernel()*RBF([1, 1, 1, 1])

    gpt_loop = 50
    y_out = np.linspace(-1, 1, gpt_loop)

    offset = np.size(xmeas)
    nsamples = 40
    #nsamples = 100

    sobp = 9
    sampler = qmc.Sobol(d=nd, scramble=False)
    test_pts = 2*sampler.random_base2(m=sobp) - 1
    for ns in range(nsamples):
        gprMdl = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=0, alpha=1e-10, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=2).fit(
                    np.hstack((xmeas, ymeas)), zmeas)

        a = wt_straddle(test_pts, gprMdl)
        I = np.argmax(a)
        #I = random.randint(0, 2**sobp-1)
        xnext = test_pts[I, :nd - 1]
        ynext = test_pts[I, 1]
        xmeas = np.vstack((xmeas, xnext))
        ymeas = np.vstack((ymeas, ynext))
        zmeas = squiggly31(xmeas, ymeas)

    # show eCDF error
    gpt = 101
    pr = np.linspace(-1, 1, gpt)
    mval = 5000
    x_val = np.random.rand(mval, nd - 1)*2-1
    y_val = pr.reshape((gpt, 1))
    yfun_true = np.zeros((gpt, 1))
    for j in range(gpt):
        nm = squiggly31(x_val, y_val[j] * np.ones((mval, 1)))
        nf = sum(nm < 0)
        yfun_true[j] = nf / mval

    straddle_errs = []
    for ns in range(nsamples + 1):
        xmeas_trunc = xmeas[:ns + offset - 1, :]
        ymeas_trunc = ymeas[:ns + offset - 1, :]
        zmeas_trunc = zmeas[:ns + offset - 1, :]

        gprMdl_trunc = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=0, alpha=1e-10, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=2).fit(
            np.hstack((xmeas_trunc, ymeas_trunc)), zmeas_trunc)

        yfun_trunc = np.zeros((gpt, 1))
        for j in range(gpt):
            nm = gprMdl_trunc.predict(np.hstack((x_val, y_val[j] * np.ones((mval, 1)))))
            nf = sum(nm < 0)
            yfun_trunc[j] = nf / mval
        errn = np.linalg.norm(yfun_true - yfun_trunc) / np.linalg.norm(yfun_true)
        straddle_errs.append(errn)

    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogy(straddle_errs)
    plt.xlabel("Number of samples")
    plt.ylabel("eCDF error")
    plt.show()

    params = gprMdl_trunc.get_params()
    print(params)
    print("learned kernel params")
    print(gprMdl_trunc.kernel_.get_params())
    print(gprMdl_trunc.kernel_.get_params()['length_scale'])
```

And for visual reference, this is what the contours of a similar test function f(x,y) look like in 2D:
[image]

As well as the sample point locations taken when the GP model zeroes out (in 2D, length scales go to the lower bound, the opposite problem as above), when before the final sample the model is pretty accurate near the zero contour.

[image]